# Setting project.version for pom dependency

Tags: maven

I need to set the value for `project.version`.  The reference to `${project.version}` will be in the pom for one of my dependencies in its dependency management section.  In other words, the dependency `org.apache.gora:gora-core:0.2.1` has parameterized the versions of its dependencies.  Just my having included gora-core as a simple dependency doesn't set `project.version` and so none of those indirect dependencies are being included in my build.

The maven documentation hasn't been much help.

Comment: Post relevant part of your pom.

Comment: So you want to have the version of your project automagically match the version of one of its dependencies?

Comment: @noahz: No, I just want to set the version to be used by the gora dependency pom and its dependencies as specified in that pom.  The version of my main maven artifact is going to be different.

Comment: should not be an issue unless you are doing things like inheriting from the dependency. It should be resolving `org.apache.gora:gora-core:0.2.1`'s transitive dependencies based on the value of `${project.version}` in `org.apache.gora:gora-core:0.2.1`'s pom (i.e. inherited from it's parent -> `0.2.1`) if it isn't then you maybe need to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me with Maven 3.0.4

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>a</groupId>
  <artifactId>b</artifactId>
  <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.gora</groupId>
      <artifactId>gora-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And when I ask Maven what the dependencies of that are:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building b 1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ b ---
[INFO] a:b:jar:1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.apache.gora:gora-core:jar:0.2.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO]    |  +- tomcat:jasper-runtime:jar:5.5.12:compile
[INFO]    |  +- tomcat:jasper-compiler:jar:5.5.12:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-api-2.1:jar:6.1.14:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api-2.5:jar:6.1.14:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-2.1:jar:6.1.14:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- ant:ant:jar:1.6.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- net.sf.kosmosfs:kfs:jar:0.3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-common-utilities:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.1.1:runtime
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.13:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-common:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |        +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |        \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.hadoop:avro:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.11:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer-ant:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO]    |     +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer-generator:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO]    |     |  +- com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.10.1:compile
[INFO]    |     |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO]    |        \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO]    \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.301s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 19 19:10:04 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

All being pulled in quite fine